# R curl sending email with attachments

Tags: r, email, curl

I am trying to send an email with attachment using R `curl`.

If I use the command line, the following succeeds in sending an email via curl from `from@mail.com` to `to@mail.com` and attaches the file `tester.pdf` (note authentication is done using SSL and the password would be horsebatterystaple):

```sh
BODY="This is the body of the email..."
SUBJECT="Did you get my last email with the reports?"

curl -v \
--url smtp://the-smtp-server:587 \
--ssl-reqd \
--mail-from from@mail.com \
--mail-rcpt to@mail.com \
--user from@mail.com:horsebatterystaple \
-F '=(;type=multipart/mixed' -F "=$BODY;type=text/plain" \
-F "file=@tester.pdf;type=application/pdf;encoder=base64" -F '=)' \
-H "Subject: $SUBJECT" \
-H "From: Myself <from@mail.com>" \
-H "To: Someone Else <to@mail.com>"
```

Now I want to translate that to `R` and the R `curl` package.

It works without attachments when I use [this](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2019/05/emayili-sending-email-from-r/) resource, but I cannot find a way to properly emulate the `-F` (form) flags.
See my attempt below.

There are no *form* arguments in the `curl` options (`curl::curl_options("form")`) and I do not find example code for `curl::form_file()` or the `mimepost` option (=> `curl::curl_options("mime")`).

Any ideas how to make this work?

Note I am not looking for `cmd <- "curl -v --url ..."; system(cmd)` type solutions if possible...

```r
h <- curl::new_handle(
  verbose = TRUE,
  url = "smtp://the-smtp-server:587",
  use_ssl = 1,
  mail_from = "from@mail.com", 
  mail_rcpt = "to@mail.com",
  username = "from@mail.com",
  password = "horsebatterystaple"
)

curl::handle_setheaders(h,
                        "Subject: Hello World",
                        "From: Myself <from@mail.com>",
                        "To: Someone Else <to@mail.com>"
)

curl::curl_fetch_memory(handle = h)
```

### Update

After reading through some more documentation, I also found `curl::send_email()`, therefore my R code is updated to the following, but the attachment still do not work... (see tries as comments):

```r
conf <- list(smpt_server = "...", ...)
verbose <- TRUE

url <- paste0("smtp://", conf$smtp_server, ":", conf$smtp_port)
message <- glue::glue('From: "{conf$name_from}" <{conf$mail_from}>
To: "{conf$name_to}" <{conf$mail_to}>
Subject: {subject}

Hi there,

this is sent from R curl...')

a <- curl::send_mail(
  mail_from = conf$mail_from, 
  mail_rcpt = conf$mail_to, 
  message = message, smtp_server = url, 
  use_ssl = TRUE, verbose = verbose,
  username = conf$mail_from, password  = conf$password,
  # mimepost = "file=@tester.pdf;type=application/pdf;encoder=base64"
  # mimepost = form_file("tester.pdf", "application/pdf")
)
```